# Передача get-параметров при php-роутинге

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, route, роутинг

возникла проблема при отправке get-запросов на сайт с простым php-роутингом.

.htaccess

```bsh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

index.php

```php
...
var_dump($_GET);
$URL = explode('/', parse_url(strip_tags($_GET['url'])), PHP_URL_PATH);
switch($URL[0]){
    case 'page1': exit(require_once('page1'));
    case 'page2': exit(require_once('page2'));
    ...
    default: exit(require_once(''));
}
...
```

page1.php

```php
<?php var_dump($_GET); ?>
```

При запросе, например: **site.ru/?var=value**

Результатом будет:

> array(1) { ["var"]=> string(5) "value" }

В то же время при запросе **site.ru/page1/?var=value**

Результат уже будет совершенно иным:

> array(1) { ["url"]=> string(6) "page1/"}
>   array(1) { ["url"]=> string(6) "page1/"}

Вопрос состоит в том, как сохранить заданные get-параметры. Заранее благодарю за ответы и помощь

З.Ы. При изменении правила в htaccess на

```bsh
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)\?*(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1&$2
```

Ничего не меняется

Comment: решение как оказалось очень простое. флаг [L] необходимо заменить на флаг [QSA]

Comment: менять то не надо было, просто добавить.

Comment: @teran если просто добавить, то будет bad gateway, я пробовал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было во флагах в htaccess, а именно необходимо было поставить флаг QSA, чтобы добавить строку запроса из запроса на замещенный URL. Флаг L пришлось убрать, так как [L, QSA] вызывало bad gateway